# Como colocar uma dropdownlist em um cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso colocar um dropdownlist nas seguintes condições: Ele vai exibir o nome da Cidade(Tabela Cidade), mas irá gravar apenas o Codigo do Funcionário. Usando essa abordagem, eu consigo montar o DropDownList:
Model

```
public class Cidade
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome da cidade é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [Display(Name="Nome")]
        public String nome { get; set; }

        public List<Cidade> ListaCidades()
        {
            return new List<Cidade>   
            {
                new Cidade { id = 1, nome = "SÃO PAULO"}  
            }; 
        }
    }
```

Veja que minha model está feita manualmente. Eu não consegui trazer os dados diretos da tabela. 
Na controller eu fiz assim(Antes estava usando na Action Errada):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            GetFuncionariosAsync funcionarios = new GetFuncionariosAsync();

            //popular a dropdown de cidades na view funcionarios
            GetCidadesAsync cidade = new GetCidadesAsync();
            var _cidade = await cidade.GetCidades();
            ViewBag.ViewCidade = new SelectList(_cidade, "id", "nome");

            var model = await funcionarios.GetFuncionarios(); 

            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: GetFuncionarios/Create
        public ActionResult Create(Cidade cidade)
        {
            var cidadeId = cidade.id;

            ViewBag.ViewCidade = new SelectList
            (
                new Cidade().ListaCidades(),
                "id",
                "nome",
                cidadeId
            );
            return View();
        }
```

e claro meu cshtml(apenas o dropdownlist) ficou assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.DropDownList("id", (SelectList)ViewBag.ViewCidade, "- Selecione -", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Veja o screenshot abaixo de como fica o dropdown, agora só preciso saber como carrego a lista do banco e se realmente eu preciso criar o método ListaCidades() na model?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que na dropdown, eu mostro a Cidade de São Paulo. Mas esta foi lançada manualmente, agora como eu listo os campos do BD? Preciso do método listacidades()? Acho ele desnecessário.

Da forma que está, se eu tento fazer dessa forma,

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
        {
            //var cidadeId = cidade.id;
            GetCidadesAsync cidade = new GetCidadesAsync();
            var _cidade = await cidade.GetCidades();
            ViewBag.ViewCidade = _cidade.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.id.ToString(), Text = s.nome });
            return View();
        }
```

eu pego o erro abaixo:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectListIterator`2[TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade,System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'
>   to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.'

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Você deve ter uma view model que inclua Cidade e Funcionários ou pode popular as Cidades do `DropDownList` em sua `Controller` e passar para a `View` em uma `ViewBag`, lembrando de já passar o item selecionado no caso da tela de edição.

Comment: Se você criar um `SelectList` na `Controller` e passar na `ViewBag` vai facilitar muito o seu trabalho. Dê uma pesquisada com essas dicas e se não conseguir implementar me avisa que eu posto uma resposta com o código.

Comment: Não, não vai, siga as instruções que eu deixei no comentário. Ps. quando eu falei na `Controller` eu me referia à do projeto Web, não na API e no método GET

Comment: O problema não é só na View, vem desde a estrutura, por hoje siga os passos que eu lhe passei e se não conseguir resolver ou entender o problema me avise, que amanhã estará resolvido. Ps.: Poste a action de GET do seu projeto Web, por enquanto esqueça o post e a sua API

Comment: Você fez isso na action de POST ou de GET do create? "Evite os Edit 2" atualize o código apresentado conforme for alterando.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa especificar que seu `ViewCidade` é um `SelectList` no `DropDownList`.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", (SelectList)ViewBag.ViewCidade, "- Selecione -", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando aqui no [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yrj5Xx)

Comment: Mesmo erro. O retorno é uma Lista de \cidades: **List<Cidade>**, isso pode dar pau? Quem é **Id**

Comment: Não, veja o exemplo aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yrj5Xx ele também é uma List<Cidade>.  O problema está certamente na sua lista. Olha no debug como ela está vindo. Ela vem id e nome?

Comment: O Id é o Id da lista cidades que será enviado via post e se ligaria(bind) a sua model.

Comment: Então, dei um debug agora e na ViewCidade eu tenho os 25 items. Os valores na ViewCidade estão em Items. Isso diz alguma coisa?

Comment: Não. Veja esse Screenshot: https://image.ibb.co/hkiogU/Capturar.png . O seu debug está assim?

Comment: Sim, só que com 25 e não 1 como o seu. Como eu estou na view Create, eu não tenho um return View(new Cidade()) e sim um redirect to index

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81466/discussion-between-netinho-santos-and-pnet).

Answer (score -3):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
        {
            GetCidadesAsync cidade = new GetCidadesAsync();
            var _cidade = await cidade.GetCidades();

            ViewBag.ViewCidade = new SelectList
            (
                _cidade,
                "id",
                "nome"
            );   
            return View();
        }
```

e no cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("cidade", (SelectList)ViewBag.ViewCidade, "- Selecione -", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```